# How do I find the realm path in react-native?

Tags: react-native, realm

I am trying to find the realm path for the react-native application I am writing. There are examples for Swift and Android to print the realm path, but I couldn't find any for react-native. Can someone please post an example of realm path retrieval using react native?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just create your Realm object and do below.

```
let realm = new Realm({
     schema: [{name: 'Dog', properties: {name: 'string'}}]
   });

   realm.write(() => {
     realm.create('Dog', {name: 'Rex'});
   });
```

`console.log(realm.path);`

Comment: Thanks for posting an example, Abhay.

Comment: Not a problem, i hoped you got your answer?

Comment: Yes, Abhay :). I am able to locate the db now and browse through it using realm browser.

Comment: How I change the path?

Answer (score 0):

try use filename instead path

```
 await Realm.open({
    path: 'test.realm',
    schema: [ImageSchema, EventSchema],
  });
```